# Design of real time sentiment analysis

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, sentiment-analysis

We're trying to design a real time sentiment analysis system (on paper) for a school project. We got some (very vague) negative feedback on how we store our data, but it isn't fully clear why this would be a bad idea or how we'd best improve this.

The setup of the system is as follows:
data from real time news RSS feeds is gathered in a kafka messaging queue, which connects to our preprocessing platform. This preprocessing step would transform all the news articles into semi-structured data, which we can do a sentiment analysis on.

We then want to store **both** the **sentiment analysis** and the preprocessed, semi-structured **news article**  for reference.
We were thinking of using MongoDB as a database to do so since you have a lot of freedom in defining different fields in the value (in the key:value pair you store) instead of Cassandra (which would be faster).

The basic use case is for people to look up an institution and get the sentiment analysis of a bunch of news articles in a certain timeframe.

As a possible improvement: do we need to use a NoSQL database or would it make sense to use a SQL database? I think our system could benefit from being denormalized (as is the case by default in NoSQL) and we wouldn't be needing any operations such as join operations that are significantly faster in SQL systems.

Does anyone know of existing systems that do similar things, for comparison?

Any input would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds perfectly reasonable, i'm not sure what exactly is the "negative feedback" you guy but it could just be personal bias. without any additional specific requirements / assumptions it's hard to give narrower advice.

Comment: The only requirements we really have is that the system should be able to recover after crashing, it should operate as quickly as possible and the database should be searchable by company and date

Comment: Sounds perfectly fine then.